# Will US Amiga 500 work in UK with UK power supply?

Tags: ntsc, amiga-500, pal, composite-video

Apart from the input voltage there are video signals (PAL, NTSC). Will I be able to use A500 that came from USA by just swapping a power supply, or any of the chips need to be replaced as well?

Comment: Depends on the screen used.But in general it will work.

Comment: Composite will try to output NTSC, what about RGB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An unmodified Amiga 500 provides two outputs:

- analogue and digital RGB through its DB23M connector
- monochrome composite through its RCA connector

Colour encoding is identical in both PAL and NTSC variants on the RGB output, and not present on the RCA connector, so the vast majority of screens with the corresponding inputs will work fine with either (they adapt to the different frequency).

If you use the RF modulator then you’d need a NTSC-compatible TV.

Apart from that, with the appropriate power supply you should be able to use a US Amiga 500 in the UK with no hardware-related problems.

If your Amiga 500 has a rev. 6 motherboard, you can add a PAL/NTSC toggle switch [without too much hassle](https://shot97retro.blogspot.com/2018/09/amiga-500-ntscpal-toggle-switch-written.html).

Comment: Worth pointing out that later Amiga 500's (and other models) switch back-and-forth between PAL/NTSC, as needed, under software control. Usually, you just set the Tool Tips on your WHDLoad icon file to automatically specify the desired video mode.